Transmision and coupling coefficient in waveguide and ring resonator

A simple ring resonator with a bus waveguide is described by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
B \\
C
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
t & \kappa \\
-\kappa^* & t^*
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A \\
D
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I don't understand though why we have -k* and t*? Shouldn't they be also k and t?
I think the conjugation concerns the phase of the circulating mode.
I appreciate any help you can provide.
Ref: Integrated Ring Resonators, D.G. Rabus, Springer





Where did the formula come from? Where did the image come from? Please provide citations.

@Andyaka Thank you for saying yes, I included the reference and photo of the book
